# Why do I always get type info printed when using python fire?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-fire

I have a simple test [python-fire](https://github.com/google/python-fire) cli program in python 2.7.15

```
import fire

class Math:
    def add(x, y):
      """add"""
      return x + y

    def multiply(x, y):
      """multiply"""
      return x * y

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fire.Fire(Math)
```

If I write

```
python-fire-test.py
```

the response from the program is

```
Type:        instance
String form: <__main__.Math instance at 0x0000000003CE89C8>

Usage:       python-fire-test.py
             python-fire-test.py add
             python-fire-test.py multiply
```

However I don't expect to see

```
Type:        instance
String form: <__main__.Math instance at 0x0000000003CE89C8>
```

printed at the top. Can I stop this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

This behavior has been replaced with cleaner output in Python Fire v0.2.0.
Upgrade Fire with `pip install -U fire` to get the latest version.

Comment: Not quite. The main problem stems from the utilization. Per the README, the operation needs to be specified along with the values to compute the result. e.g. `python python-fire-test.py add 5 5` would be the correct way I believe.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems in your code. The more immediate one as to why you are actually getting the result you are seeing is because of a misuse of the library.

The result you are getting is in fact simply the result of `fire.Fire(Math)`, which is a representation of the instance object you are getting from `fire.Fire(Math)`.

Your utilization should in fact be this:

```
(venv) ➜ python python-fire-test.py multiply 5 5
25
(venv) ➜ python python-fire-test.py add 5 5     
10
```

However, there is another problem you are facing that won't get you that result either now. In your code you are creating a class called `Math`. In your instance methods (`add`, `multiply`), you are going to face issues when you try to use it, due to the fact you are not passing the necessary explicit reference for the instance itself `self`. So, your code should now be:

import fire

```
class Math:
    def add(self, x, y):
      """add"""
      return x + y

    def multiply(self, x, y):
      """multiply"""
      return x * y

if __name__ == '__main__':
  fire.Fire(Math)
```

A little further down in the README for the lib you are using the utilization is shown as:

```
python calculator.py double 10  # 20
python calculator.py double --number=15  # 30
```